# Appcelerator. Options dialog is opening several times when refreshing table

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

Titanium SDK version: 1.7.0.RC1
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am developing an iOS app in Appcelerator. I am retrieving tweets from twitter and inserting them into a table. For each row/tweet I am also extracting the containing links for that individual tweet/row and the user can select them from an options dialog which is opened when the row is clicked.

The problem is that if I reload the page and click the row, two dialogs are open upon each other. If I click three times, three dialogs is opened and so on. How can I make sure that the dialog only opens once?

This is my code: http://pastie.org/2004091

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Especially on the iPhone 3G as this runs slowly and you're more tempted to tap things more than once. The way I got around it is to either remove the event listener from within the event listener itself. Or you set a variable and test for its value in the event listener. So, if you set a variable call 'clicked' to false. When the listener is first check for 'clicked' = false, if it is set it to true so next time the code is not executed.